# Is there any way to serialize a non-serializable class?

Tags: java, serialization, java-7

I want to save my school objects to my database with serialization. Problem is I can update School class and implement serializable interface but problem is there are too many fields like Student, CityInfo and non of them are serializable. Is there any way to serialize School object with all these fields without updating classes?

```
public class School{
    private Student student;
    private CityInfo info;
    ....

}
```

Comment: What kind of `School` has only one `Student`? Why would you want to store serialized Java objects in a database, where their values can't be queried?

Comment: @Andreas Its just an example Class. I don't want to query their fields but I want to get this object from another java application. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own serialization and deserialization methods.

Take a look at the "Customize the protocol" section here.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html

Comment: There are hundreds of fields and Its so hard to implement my own serialization and deserialization methods for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Java byte-code serialization is concerned, this cannot be done without customizing the serialization process.

> As it says here: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=34802
>
> "When you serialize an object, the serialization mechanism works by chaining up the inheritence hierarchy, saving the sate of each Serializable superclass in turn. When serialization reaches the first non-serializable superclass, the serialization stops.
>
> When deserializing, the state of this first non-serializable superclass is restored not from the stream, but by invoking that class' no-argument constructor. If the no-argument constructor is not adequate for your purposes, you must customize the serialization of your subclass with writeObject() and readObject() in order to write out and restore any information from the non-serializable superclass that you find necessary."

However, why must you use the built in Java serialization?  There are many libraries out there that will serialize your public fields(and fields with appropriate getters and setters) to JSON, XML or some other format.  This also has the added benefit of making your data more portable.